# CSS page transition by adding & removing a class (Vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, css

I'm attempting to create a transition that quickly fades in the page on load and then when a link is clicked, the page fades out and moves up slightly.

To do this I created the class 'is-loaded' which I would apply to the elements ('wrapper' and 'page-fade'). When the document is loaded, the 'is-loaded' class would be added, then when a link is clicked, the same class would be removed from both elements.

The code:

```
.wrapper {
transform: translateY(-25px);
transition: transform cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) 0.3s; 
}

.wrapper.is-loaded {
transform: translateY(0); 
}

.page-loader {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #ffffff;
z-index: 999999;
transition: opacity cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) 0.4s, visibility cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.95) 0.4s; 
}

.page-loader.is-loaded {
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden; 
}
```

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function() {

    event.preventDefault()

    var i = this.getAttribute('href')
    var wrapper = document.querySelector('wrapper');
    var pageloader = document.querySelector('page-loader');

        wrapper.classList.remove('is-loaded'),
      setTimeout(function() {
        pageloader.classList.remove('is-loaded');
      }, 80),
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = i
      }, 100)
  })
})

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var wrapper = document.querySelectorAll('wrapper');
  var pageloader = document.querySelectorAll('page-loader');

  wrapper.classList.add('is-loaded'),
  pageloader.classList.add('is-loaded');
})
```

I'm new to writing in JavaScript so i'm unsure why my code does nothing. Is there a way to get this to work? No jQuery please and just vanilla js. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the prefix [selector notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors#Types_of_selectors) `.` necessary to find `'wrapper'` or `'page-loader'` with `document.querySelector()`|`document.querySelectorAll()`. In both cases, you'd use the same kind of selector syntax as you do in your CSS.

```
var wrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper'); 
var pageloader = document.querySelectorAll('.page-loader');
```

Also, `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a(n `Array`-like) [HTML NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which doesn't have a `classList` property. [You could convert the NodeList to an `Array`](https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array) and iterate through the result, adding to the `classList` of each element *or*, if you know there's only **one** of what you're looking for on the page, swap `document.querySelectorAll()` for `document.querySelector()` — which will return a single element.

Comment: Perfect, guess I missed something pretty simple, adding `.` and using `document.querySelector()` did the trick. Thank you!